# how to write an EF query to join three tables and order by a field?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have the following 3 tables structured in the way as shown below. I am trying to write an entity framework join query among the 3 tables
to

```
Select joblink, usersubmitted, runstatus, submitted_time, changelist 
orderby submitted time
```

I was able to join and retrieve data from 2 tables but cant figure out
on how to join 3 tables, can anyone provide guidance on how to do this?

```
lookahead_run (Table#1) 
+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
lookahead_run_id(PK)|joblink |  usersubmitted |submitted_time     |runstatus
+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
15963---------------+link1---+---username1----+2017-03-17 22:28:53--Fail-----


lookahead_run_change_list (Table#2)
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
changelistid(PK)|lookahead_run_id|change_list_id
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
38591-----------+15963-----------+34022
38590-----------+15963-----------+34021
38589-----------+15963-----------+34020


change_lists (Table#3)
+-------------+-----------+
change_list_id|changelist
+-------------+-----------+
34022--------  1823900
34021--------  1819483
34020--------  1818572
```

UPDATED CODE;-

```
namespace Dashboard.Model.ApiModels
{
    public class LookaheadRunInfo
    {
        public string ECJobLink { get; set; }
        public List<String> gerrits { get; set; }
        public string UserSubmitted { get; set; }
        public string SubmittedTime { get; set; }
        public string RunStatus { get; set; }
    }
}

        public IEnumerable<LookaheadRunInfo> GetLookaheadRunInfoSearch(LookaheadRunsFilterCriteria filterCriteria)
        {
            List<LookaheadRunInfo> lookaheadRunsInfo = new List<LookaheadRunInfo>();           
            var lookaheadRunData = bitDB.lookahead_run.OrderBy(x => x.lookahead_run_id).Skip(filterCriteria.PageNumber * filterCriteria.PageSize).Take(filterCriteria.PageSize).ToList();
            foreach (var lookaheadRunRow in lookaheadRunData)
            {
                var lookaheadRunId = lookaheadRunRow.lookahead_run_id;
                 lookaheadRunsInfo = (from lrcl in bitDB.lookahead_run_change_list
                                                 join cl in bitDB.change_lists on lrcl.change_list_id equals cl.change_list_id
                                                 join lr in bitDB.lookahead_run on lrcl.lookahead_run_id equals lr.lookahead_run_id
                                                 where lrcl.lookahead_run_id == lookaheadRunId
                                                 orderby lr.submission_time
                                                 select new LookaheadRunInfo
                                                 {
                                                     lr.ec_job_link,
                                                     cl.change_requests,
                                                     lr.submitted_by,
                                                     lr.submission_time,
                                                     lr.lookahead_run_status,

                                                 }).ToList();
            }
            return lookaheadRunsInfo;
        }
```

Error:-

```
Error   1   Cannot initialize type 'Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.LookaheadRunInfo' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put as many joins as you like in a query. if you want to select fields from multiple entities, you need to select a new object. I would suggest you to create a holder class to contain the joined contents, but i'm gonna show you how to do it with an anonymous type:

```
var lookaheadRunChangeListIds = (from lrcl in bitDB.lookahead_run_change_list
    join cl in bitDB.change_lists on lrcl.change_list_id equals cl.change_list_id
    join lr in bitDB.lookahead_run on lrcl.lookahead_run_id equals lr.lookahead_run_id
    where lrcl.lookahead_run_id == lookaheadRunId
    orderby lr.submitted_time
    select new LookaheadRunInfo { 
        ECJobLink = lr.joblink, 
        UserSubmitted = lr.usersubmitted, 
        RunStatus = lr.runstatus, 
        SubmittedTime = lr.submitted_time, 
        gerrits = cl.changelist 
    }).ToList();
```

Note that the `new { ... }` can be replaced by a `new NewClass { ... }` where the `NewClass` contains all the selected fields.

**Edit above:** name your properties as you instanciate your `LookAheadRun` since the names are different, you should map them.

Comment: I incorporated all your suggestions ,creaed a new class aswell but running into an error..I updated the question with the code and error,can you help on how to fix it?

Comment: also `change_requests`is of Icollection type..how to convert it to List<string> ?

Comment: I already figured what you updated in your question,my current problem is the second comment I added above,I get the error `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`..I tried as `cl.change_list.ToString().Tolist()` which didnt work

Comment: As stated in my example,its possible to get multiple values of change_lists for a lookaheadrun id...so am not sure join will work in this case..please clarify

Comment: the easiest way is to use navigation properties and select it. You can read about them there : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: can you provide a specific example on how to use this?it willreally help to understand...also do you agree join would not work in this case...the answer you posted wouldnt work,right?I want to know what is the best practice to achieve my goal

Comment: Sorry, but it becomes too broad. I think you should spend some time on EF tutorials. You can start somewhere like http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx. Note that I pointed to the relationship part since that's where you get info about the navigation properties.